# spring-integration amqp reject message if not procced

Tags: spring-integration, amqp

I need solve this scenario. I have two amqp consumer set to fetch one message.

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow jmsPrimaryFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(
        Amqp.inboundGateway(
            taskManager().getPrimaryMessageListenerContainer()).errorChannel(errorChannel())
        )
        .channel(taskChannel())
        .get();
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow jmsSecondaryFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(
        Amqp.inboundGateway(
            taskManager().getSecondaryMessageListenerContainer()).errorChannel(errorChannel())
            .autoStartup(false)
        )
        .channel(taskChannel())
        .get();
}
```

taskChannel is queuechannel but allow only one message consume at once so no parallel processing.
How can I reject one message after some timeout if another message took too long to proceed. 
so this message will returned back to queue to proceed by another node? Just I mean that those two consumer prefetch two messages but only one can be processed at once so how release second prefetched message if the first one took to long to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not clear. You could set a capacity limit (say 1) on the queue channel and set a sendTimeout on the gateway. Then, if the queue is full, attempts to add messages will fail after the timeout. However, using a queue channel in this scenario is dangerous - you can lose messages if the server fails because messages are ack'd as soon as they are deposited in the queue.

If you use a `RendezvousChannel` instead, the producer will block waiting for the consumer to receive the message.

But bear in mind, even this single message can be lost if the server crashes after the handoff.

Comment: OK thanks, just I have to change the way as this was wrong way. :) Just better is to do not have more than one consumer per one type of message. So I split messages to different types and route them with routing key. Anyway thanks for help.